# Is it necessary to add the root certificates to Java Keystore?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, jks

In SSL handshake, server need to present the chain of certificates up to the root certificate, but the root itself is optional, right? So is it necessary to add root certificate to java keystore?

Answer (score 5):

Not if you have good reason to believe the peer already trusts a lower certificate in the chain.

Comment: But if the peer only trusts the root CAs?

Comment: The peer has to trust something in the chain. If it's only the root, you have to include the root. I'm curious why you're even asking. What would be the point of going to all the extra trouble to remove bits from the chain?

Comment: Key store is used to store a server's public key certificate and the chain of certificates that link it to a root certificate. The chain of certificates is presented to the client at the time of TLS handshake. But according to TLS protocol, the server need not send the root certificate itself. The client wouldn't trust the chain unless the root is already in his trust store. And the intermediate certificate next to the root would have the fingerprint of the root as well so it shouldn't be difficult to find the correct root from a bunch of roots that would complete the chain.

Comment: I'm making an SSL client with client side authentication (2 way SSL). I first wrote the client in python (openssl library) and I only provided my key & certificate (the cert is directly signed be the root) without the root and it worked. But this doesn't seem to be the case in java? 
But here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65332/ssl-root-certificate-optional it says according to TLS standard, root need not be presented, so that left me a bit confused.